# Clip tool in ArcGIS Pro not working?

Tags: raster, dem, clip, arcgis-pro, terrain

I'm trying to clip "Terrain" raster I downloaded from the portal (https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=58a541efc59545e6b7137f961d7de883) in the shape of a polygon (a country's boundaries) by using "Clip" tool but the tool doesn't work properly. It gets stuck at 2% while running.

What could be the reason?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3.

Comment: Maybe try with 2.3.0

Comment: Use QGIS with XYZ tiles - add a new connection (this works with ESRI basemaps as well) then save the raster. Alternatively, download the DEM from USGS, NASA or other sources.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot clip raster per the documentation of the Clip tool: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/clip.htm. It's intended for feature classes/layers. What I usually do is Extract By Mask as mentioned by Villard above, making sure that the Parameters and Environments are set appropriately. The two other ways are to use Clip Raster tool (can use Mosaic datasets and Image Sevice Layers) or Export Raster pane (ie. clip by extent in Environment or with geometry/graphic...).

1. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/extract-by-mask.htm
2. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clip.htm
3. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/export-or-convert-raster-datasets.htm

Answer (score 0):

How large is the area you are trying to clip? There is a cap on image size "The layer is restricted to a 5,000 x 5,000 pixel limit in a single request." Probably your area is larger than that. Try clipping smaller areas or a grid instead and then mosaic the smaller areas together.

And for what purpose do you need this data? For analysis please check the note in the item description on resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Use extract by mask instead of clip.

Comment: Not sure this answers the question, even if it is a better technique...